# PyQT5: Iterate all items in QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a QFileSystemModel to display all files in a folder within a QListView item. This works how I want it to, but now I'd like to get the filenames with path of all the files that are shown in the QListView.

My code for the Interface looks like this:

```
    self.input_ = QListView()
    self.input_model = QFileSystemModel()
    self.input_model.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Files)
    self.input_.setModel(self.input_model)
    self.input_.setRootIndex(self.input_model.index(self.path))
    self.input_model.setNameFilters(self.filters)
    self.input_model.setNameFilterDisables(False)
    self.input_.setRootIndex(
      self.input_model.setRootPath(self.path))
```

I already tried the SelectAll() and getIndexes() methods of the QListView Object, but for some reason the SelectAll() doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems an odd way to do things.  Why not just use a [recursive `QDirIterator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#details), e.g. `iter = QDirIterator(self.path, QDirIterator.Subdirectories)` .

Comment: For my programm I want a QListView to show the contents of folders. Furthermore I filter the files that are shown. Since the filtered files are already there, i thought it would be nice to get them from the QListView or QFileSystemModel.

Comment: hey, I am working for same project , any solution ?